# How to install my server's self-signed certificate on an iPad

Tags: ipad, ssl, x509certificate

Is there a way to install my own self-signed SSL certificate on my iPad? Presumably I can get the .crt via Dropbox or email, but then what do I do with it? Is there an easier way to get the .crt than that (from a PC)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might help found this Apple Support post:

> I would import the cert on a desktop system through Firefox, then export with private key in `.p12` form. Email the resulting cert and you should be all set.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2652502&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even need to do that. I just mailed the .crt to my Gmail account and clicked on it on the iPad and it installed it with no problem. I wonder what happens if I ever want to remove it.

Comment: I'm sure there's an app for that ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is very easy . You can just put your certificate in your server where it can be accessed via a browser. Than just visit the location in your browser Eg. Safari in ipad just click on the certificate.

Comment: This was indeed the simplest solution for me

Comment: This is not true. The certificate is not added to the device but only to the trusted certificates of the safari browser